# Macbook Pro Retina 15" (late 2013), is it possible to run 1 extra display at 60hz in a best resolution than full hd?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, resolution, 4k

Sorry but I have read a lot on this topic, in threads of this platform and multiple articles .. etc. And I'm still not sure what resolution and frequency my laptop can run on an external monitor.

**Laptop:** Macbook Pro 15 "Retina (Late 2013)
**Connections:** 2 Thunderbolts, 1 HDMI

**About what I would like:**

- I want to add 1 new monitor to work on a double screen: monitor + laptop screen.
- I'm thinking about 27 "- 32" with a resolution somewhat higher than FullHD.
- In this way I hope not to notice too much negative ppi difference compared to the Retina display

**About Freq y Res:**

- I don't want 30hz or 24hz with higher resolutions;
- I would like to know the **maximum resolution** for an external display **at 60hz.**
  QuadHD, 2K, 4K? I have no idea.

I have read about MST and 60hz at 4k works with this computer, but I do not understand too much how it works and if this affects me. Because I want to connect only 1 additional monitor.

Now, knowing this maximum resolution at 60hz, I will be able to decide to buy a monitor that best suits the requirements.

And now what cable or adapter do I need so that everything works correctly without limitations?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.3-15-dual-graphics-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html)

"This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI."

**EveryMac** is your friend when it comes to Mac details and specs. I find it better (often) than the official Apple support site.